# Koa.js: Only the first middleware executes, all others fail

Tags: node.js, koa2

I seem to have an issue with only one middleware able to run in Koa.js

```
import "@babel/polyfill";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import "isomorphic-fetch";
import graphQLProxy, { ApiVersion } from "@shopify/koa-shopify-graphql-proxy";
import Koa from "koa";
import next from "next";
import session from "koa-session";
import * as handlers from "./handlers/index";
import { verifyRequest } from "@shopify/koa-shopify-auth";
dotenv.config();

import Middleware from './middleware';
import router from './router';


const middleware = new Middleware();


////// Application Config //////
let port;
if (process.env.PORT) {
  port = process.env.PORT;
} else port = 8081;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({dev});
const handleRequests = app.getRequestHandler();
const { SHOPIFY_API_SECRET } = process.env;


////// Application Instantiation //////
app
  .prepare().then(() => {
  const server = new Koa();

  ////// Middleware //////

  // loggers
  server.use(async (ctx: any, next: any) => {
    console.log(ctx, `=====ctx=====`)
    await next();
  });
  server.use(async (ctx: any, next: any) => {
    console.log(ctx.request, `=====ctx.request=====`) // doesn't log
    await next();
  });

 // shopify
  server.use(session(server));
  server.keys = [SHOPIFY_API_SECRET] as string[];
  server.use(middleware.instantiateShopify());
  server.use(
    graphQLProxy({version: (ApiVersion as unknown as any).October19}));
  server.use(verifyRequest());
  server.use((ctx: any) => handleRequests(ctx.req, ctx.res));

  ////// Routing //////

  server.use(router.allowedMethods());
  server.use(router.routes());

  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

In the above code the 2nd log statement doesn't execute. Also the rest of the application is broken and I see `"Not Found"` in browser.

**Tried**

Removing the logging middlewares allows the application to at least display in browser.

Reversing the order of the logging middlewares allows the first one to run, only.

Removing `await next();` doesn't fix the issue.

There do not appear to be any console/terminal errors.

Does anyone know what else could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
server.use( async (ctx: any, next: any) => {
    console.log(ctx, `=====ctx=====`)
    next();
  });
  server.use(async (ctx: any, next: any) => {
    console.log(ctx.request, `=====ctx.request=====`) // doesn't log
    next();
  });
```

i hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks, in both middlewares Typescript shows this error: `server/server.ts:42:26 - error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.

42   server.use(middleware, async (ctx: any, next: any) => {
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
43     console.log(ctx.request, `=====ctx.request=====`)
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
44     await next();
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
45   });
   ~~~
`

Comment: remove async next(); and simply write next();

Comment: Yes, now both loggers run (I had to remove `middleware` from argument 1). But the shopify code still does not for some reason. Maybe I need to wrap them in a function and add `next()` as well?

Comment: why not try to create a normal function and execute something like this,  server.use(() => { middleware.instantiateShopify() }); and try to simplify things do some changes like                                                                               
                                                                                                                 import middleware from './middleware';

and use this middleware directly rather then                                            
   import Middleware from './middleware';


const middleware = new Middleware();

Comment: Ok, could that be the source of the issues?

Comment: it can be because we never create another const after importing it...it might run into another problem let me know if it helped...

Comment: I brought the middleware declaration into the same file (and called it directly) but it does not seem to have fixed the issue unfortunately

Comment: why not call next() in all the app.use() in order to execute all app.use statements one after the another it might get messy  but you should try once it might help you figure out where the problem is